# How to restrict object creation with generics?

Tags: java, generics

I want to have a type hierarchy where only `Foo` objects are in control of the creation of `Bar` objects. E.g:

```
public abstract class Foo<F extends Foo<F>> {
    public abstract  Bar<F> makeBar();
}

public abstract class Bar<F extends Foo<F>> {}
```

Now a subclass of Foo could implement a subclass of Bar and give it back:

```
public class FooImpl extends Foo<FooImpl> {

    private static class BarImpl extends Bar<FooImpl> {}

    @Override
    public Bar<FooImpl> makeBar() { return new BarImpl(); }
}
```

However that does still allow the creation of `Bar`s elsewhere:

```
public class FakeBar extends Bar<FooImpl> {}
```

How can I restrict `Bar<FooImpl>` (using only the type system, not runtime checks) in a way that it **must** be created by an instance of `FooImpl`, and **cannot** be created in any other place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well instead of relying on generics etc, a simpler way to accomplish this is to enforce that you need an instance of `Foo` to create a `Bar`

```
public Bar(Foo foo){...}
```

This way, no one can create a bar independently of `Foo`. This couples the 2 classes, and indicates to users of this fact as well. There are other ways to accomplish this as well... this is just one example

Comment: I really want that you must **ask** a `Foo` subclass for a `Bar`. In your version all I could do would be a runtime check if `Foo` really created that `Bar`.

Comment: Well, ok, but what is the purpose of this? What does anyone gain by only getting Bar from Foo and nowhere else? This is what you need to answer

Comment: @Java Drinker: A subclass like `FooImpl` contains a certain subclass `BarImpl` of `Bar<FooImpl>`, which should be pretty much hidden from the outside (which sees only `Bar`s). The point is when `FooImpl` gets back a `Bar<FooImpl>` instance, it needs to cast it back to the original `BarImpl`, which is only safe if we are sure that it really was created by `FooImpl` in the first place. Runtime checks *might* be good enough if you have complete control over the code, but this is not necessarily the case.

Comment: Ok, that's fair, but again, why does FooImpl need to cast it back to a BarImpl? If you have an abstract class or interface, it's functionality should be accessed via the public api. I guess what I want to know is, what does FooImpl get from BarImpl, that it cannot get from Bar<FooImpl> for example?

Comment: @Java Drinker: I want to have a kind of "framework" that deals with `Bar`s only. That means, a method of the framework would accept a `BarImpl` (it's a `Bar` after all), but after processing/transforming it, its type would be lost, and all I had would be a Bar<FooImpl>. The whole point is to write the code as general as possible. To deal with this, I make the `Bar`s as dumb as possible and put the logic in the `Foo`s. But I still need to retrieve that data in a safe way.

Comment: In fact I did it in a similar way, which seems to work well: `Bar` is `final and requires on every access an instance of the `Foo` instance it has as type parameter. `Foo` itself must keep its instances hidden from the outside. You can still generate runtime exceptions by using a `null` ref or raw types, but I think it's OK to got shoot in the foot if you try to cheat...

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't work (with the limitation: type system only, no runtime checks). We can either disallow subclassing in general (`final` class) or allow it. If a (public) class is not final, any other class may subclass.

You could try playing with annotations - like inventing an annotation, that lists *allowed* classname, but this depends on processing the annotations.

Example:

```
@AllowedSubclasses(classnames="com.example.FooBar; *.AnyFooBar; com.example.foobars.*")
public abstract class Bar<F extends Foo<F>> {}
```

The annotation processor then would throw an error, if any other class subclasses this annotated class.

---

What about a mixed approach: annotate your internal methods with "HANDS OFF" in the javaDoc and document, that any violation will result in runtime exceptions. After the method has been called, you can verify within the method, if the caller is an instance of one of the classes, that are allowed to use this feature.

Comment: I thought along the lines of "build something in" that only subclasses of `Foo` have control over (protected inner classes?), but I can't get it running.

Comment: Even if there was away - the weapon "reflection/invocation API" can destroy any of those shields.

Comment: If it would be safe for "normal" use, it would be good enough. If someone uses reflection and it blows up in his face, well...

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something the type system can (or should) do. You want access restrictions, use Java's access modifiers. But I don't think those can implement your very specific and unusual requirements either.

Actually, I don't think they can be implemented at all: you want a class to be publically visible and non-final, yet allow the ability to call its constructors *and* to extend it only to a specific class and its subclasses?

Sorry, no can do. What would be the point anyway?

Comment: "What would be the point anyway?" Type classes like in Haskell or Scala.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `makeBar` a concrete method which calls a `protected abstract makeBar0` which does the actual creation. makeBar() can take the result and check it the object any way you wish.

```
public abstract class Foo<F extends Foo<F>> {
    public Bar<F> makeBar() {
        Bar<F> bar = makeBar0();
        // check bar
        return bar;
    }
}
```

If you prefer you could add a check on the creation of Foo which may be more performance. i.e. check the return type of makeBar0();

Comment: Could you please elaborate this a little bit, it sounds interesting, but I don't quite get it...

Comment: that relies on runtime checks in `makeBar()`, which the OP wants to avoid.  (And I think you meant to say `makeBar()` should be a concrete **method**.)

Comment: @Stephen C, Thank you.  A runtime check shouldn't be a big issue because its a rule which shouldn't be violated too regularly. i.e. any developer will only do it a few times before they work out what to do. ;)